# std::function as Method Parameter Between Classes

Tags: c++, class, c++17

When I pass method name to other class method, it shows this error:

```
$ g++ test.cpp -std=c++17
test.cpp: In member function ‘void Test::finish()’:
test.cpp:18:38: error: invalid use of non-static member function ‘bool 
Test::local_method(std::__cxx11::string)’
         t.add_method(local_method);
                                  ^
test.cpp:16:14: note: declared here
     bool local_method(string msg) {}
```

`test.cpp`:

```
#include <functional>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Main {
    public:
        void add_method(function<bool(string)> fn) {
            // ...
        }
};
Main t;

class Test {
    public:
        bool local_method(string msg) {}
        void finish() {
            t.add_method(local_method);
        }
};

int min() {
    Test a;
    a.finish();
}
```

while it works in other codes when I didn't use class:

```
void call(int a, function<int(int)> x) {
    cout << "--->>>" << x(a) << endl;
}
int give_an_int(int a) {
    return a * 123;
}
call(11, give_an_int);
```

Comment: Post a [mcve] reproducing your problem as required here please.

Comment: you are calling a function which is  not static and you have no instance of the class in you Test class

Comment: `Main main;` Ary you trying to code java in c++?

Comment: `Main ` has not been instantiated. So there is no code created for `local_method`.

Comment: @lakeweb `Main` was instantiated as a global variable.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I've updated the code.

Comment: `local_method` accepts two parameters while function is supposed to be called with just one, so to form a function object you need to bind class instance context.

Comment: @mortezaipo You're still lacking a [mcve], sorry.

Comment: Thanks @πάντα ῥεῖ  I went too fast. So main is not static so there is no way for Test, as a declaration, to find it.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ post updated ;)